# Passing a label of a form to a ClassModule function

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to pass a label as object to a class module. I'm simply trying to pass the Reference of the object to another function, which would be simple in object-oriented langs, but somehow in vba I don't find the solution.... 
The class module is doing hard work and is used by different forms. It would be great to give the class module reference to a label, just to give the user a status feedback.

(simplyfied)
Form:

```
 GenericExcelImporter.SetStatusLabel Me.lbReadState
```

ClassModule:

```
Public Sub SetStatusLabel(ByRef lb As Label)
    Set StatusLabel = lb
End Sub
```

This causes error "Object variable not set (Error 91)"

Strange enough this example does the same:

```
Dim l As Label
Set l = Me.lbReadState
l.Caption = l.Caption    ' no error, so the reference seems to be working
GenericExcelImporter.SetStatusLabel l   'error 91
```

Comment: `GenericExcelImporter` is definitely instantiated?

Comment: I can't replicate this. Could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Are you using a `Class` or a `Module`? These are different things in VBA. A Module is like a static Class. A class needs to be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

-.- thanks for your help. Ms Access selected the Me.lbReadState as error source, but you were right, it was the class module....I didn't know that ending the debugging mode clears the global vars, even if nothing is changed at the form....